# TypeError: undefined is not an object 'installCoreFunctions' react-native-reanimated [iOS]

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

Tried with

```
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                             launchOptions:launchOptions];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                    moduleName:@"MyApp"
                                             initialProperties:nil];
```

But now this gives another error and the app doesn't build

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate sourceURLForBridge:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x283b010e0'
```

On updating

```
initialProperties:nil
```

to

```
initialProperties:${}
```

by following https://gist.github.com/ybonnetain/7b3e510050447ae52c0f8d6dd741d9d4

it gives a new error

```
Use of undeclared identifier '$'
```

My current [AppDelegate.m](https://wtools.io/paste-code/bF3S)

```
react-native 0.70.1
react 18.1.0
react-native-reanimated 2.9.1
```

[image: com.facebook.react.JavaScript (9): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xffffa0000c250698)]
[image]
[image]
`com.facebook.react.JavaScript (9): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xffffa0000c250698)`

Answer (score 1):

**I suspect something about the JSI module not having the VM reference early on.**

Make sure to init react root view using the appropriate initialiser with the help of `RCTBridgeDelegate`, not `RCTRootView::initWithBundleURL`.

**Here is your header file (.h)**

it might be in the .m if it is not used anywhere else. 
Anyways, it must declare that the implementation will conform to `RCTBridgeDelegate`.

```objectivec
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate>
@end
```

**Here is your implementation file details (.m)**

You have to import:

- header where the protocol is defined
- bundle URL provider
- react root view

```objectivec
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
```

Because you conform to the protocol mentionned above you have to implement the `sourceURLForBridge` method.
With that we will be able to create a bridge instance and it will know where to look for the JS bundle. 
Here `RCTBundleURLProvider` might be ok for both debug and release builds, I do not remember but adapt to your own needs.

```objectivec
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}
```

Now in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` hook you will need to

1. create the bridge instance
2. init the React view by passing the bridge reference to it.

```objectivec
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self // -> self because it is self that conforms to RCTBridgeDelegate
                                            launchOptions:launchOptions];
  
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"MyApp"
                                            initialProperties:@{}];
  
  rootView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  
  self.window.rootViewController = rootView;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  
  return YES;
}

@end
```

Now `InnerNativeModule.installCoreFunctions` error should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks for such an elaborative answer.
"I do not remember but adapt to your own needs." I am not clear what changes I will have to make. With your current code I am getting the following error:
`No visible @interface for 'RCTBundleURLProvider' declares the selector 'jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:fallbackResource:'` Please help. My updated AppDelegate.m https://wtools.io/paste-code/bF7c. My updated AppDelegate.h https://wtools.io/paste-code/bF7d

Comment: It looks that method was deprecated. Look at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33451#issuecomment-1083618881

Comment: Made the changes, but now the xcode seems to be stuck in an infinite loop, and it gets stopped at a point repeatedly without there being a breakpoint. Added the xcode screenshot the questions.

Comment: Does it not compile or is it a runtime error ? Have you tried a clean build ?

Comment: Yes, did clean the build. The app is crashing on just starting inside the `InstallCoreFunction`. :(

Comment: I don’t known what’s happening here. Maybe you could raise a new github issue to these guys

Comment: Ok, I did. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34867